# Stuck with upgrade tool - upgrader window out of screen

Tags: 13.04, 13.10, upgrade, window, cinnamon

What the title says. Important bit is that also 'OK' and 'Cancel' buttons are out of screen boundary too, thus un-clickable. Because of the nature of upgrade, I can't close and start again.

Background: was doing upgrade from 13.04 -> 13.10, clicked the details button to took a look at package changes. Sporting Cinnamon. Additionally, where I should file the bug report? This is intolerable. I *knew* I should have used the terminal instead.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and drag the window (from any point of its corresponding area) just as if you're dragging its header. In your case upwards, so you can see the buttons.

Another solution is to resize its height from the top, then drag it by its header.

Comment: Accepted! Especially, the first one, "Alt to move window" - didn't know that (it's also simpler than resizing and then moving, why didn't I think about that?).